# How to run both Dojo 1.7 and Dojo 1.6?

Tags: dojo

It is possible to load both dojo 1.6 and dojo 1.7 on the same page?  I've seen examples of loading two versions prior to 1.7 and different 1.7 versions but nothing which mixes 1.6 with 1.7.   Looking for something like http://jsfiddle.net/neonstalwart/44e56/ but with 1.6 and 1.7.

Comment: Is there any particular reason for why you would need to do this?

Comment: I would like to use ESRI's JSAPI (built on 1.6.1) but use the 'define(['a'], function (a) { return declare(...); });' syntax for my modules.

Comment: I can get it limping along (http://jsfiddle.net/qvyTe/) but still need to use dojo.require for 1.6.1 modules.  I *think* we should be able to load 1.6.1 modules via the 1.7.2 loader but I'm not clear on how.

Comment: The [documentation on AMD](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/amd) suggests it is supported, though I haven't tried it.

Answer (score 1):

The Dojo 1.7 loader [supports legacy Dojo 1.6 syntax](http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/loader/legacy) (dojo.require/dojo.provides) along side the newer define().  You can easily do this in synchronous mode (Dojo does not have the full benefit of using asynchronous I/O) or in the various other legacy modes mentioned in the documentation.  There should be no need to host two copies of Dojo on your page.

Answer (score 0):

Dojo 1.7 supports both the old 1.6 and new 1.7 way to create your own widgets.